# How to create a new session in Angualr 2?

Tags: angular

In Node we will create a session in express session.

But in Angular 2 when the user needs to login it requires an API call for  authentication. Where API's are for data service. Then where we create a session in Angular 2 app?

Answer (score 0):

A session is created automatically on the backend server. You request the browser to display url and send it to the server. Then the server handles request and creates a session.

To create a new session you should Sign Off. Then Sign In again.

Comment: How can we add customize the data in session.

Answer (score 0):

A seesion is created on the backend, which would response a JSESSIONID to browser. If HTTP request with same JSESSIONID, it will be in same session.

So if you want to create a new session, http request need to set

```
withCredentials:false
```

Try to change your code like this

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: false });

this.http.post(this.connectUrl, <stringified_data> , options)...
```